# SOAP Envelope Size

Tags: soap, envelope

I'll ask the question first, and then give some background:
**Does anyone know if the SOAP Envelope Size is calculated including the headers, or just the content outside of the tags?**

Content-Length includes the header information, but I can't assume that Content-Length = Envelope Size. The SOAP specification doesn't seem to address the Envelope Size, and I'm starting to worry that it's a "Up to the implementer" kind of thing.

Any answers or leads would be great.

Comment: `Content-Length` is the body size of the response. If you are doing SOAP over HTTP then the SOAP XML is the body. What need do you have for the SOAP envelope size?

Comment: I'm dealing with CWMP and I'm testing the 9004 error, which requires exceeding the maximum SOAP Envelope size, in this particular case.

Comment: Then just pack the SOAP message with as much data as you can and send it out.

Comment: Well I need to make sure that it will throw the error even if it's one byte over the maximum, which is why I need to know the size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the if it exceeds maximum size you can do this way:

```
      if (maxMessageSize > 0) {
            FixedByteArrayOutputStream fbaos = new FixedByteArrayOutputStream(maxMessageSize);
            try {

            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                handleException("Error in checking the message size", e, synCtx);
            } catch (SynapseException syne) {
                synLog.traceOrDebug("Message size exceeds the upper bound for caching, request will not be cached");
                return;
            } finally {
                try {
                    fbaos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    handleException("Error occurred while closing the FixedByteArrayOutputStream ", e, synCtx);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it though. So I have asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45229700/3599535)